# python: how can i create a list of integers,to a number?

Tags: python, list

I receive an input int that I don't previously know. How can I create a new list of integer from 0 to that int? An easy way please. Thank you in advance.
I mean that:
k = n
...
list = [0, ... , k]

Comment: It's worth noting, this isn't the site to ask people to write code for you. People will be happy to help in most cases, however, so long as you have shown that you have really made your own effort first ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
numbers = list(range(k+1))   # For Python 2, it is just range(k+1).
```

Given an integer `k`, which you can get with `input`.

The `range` creates an iterator (in Python 3) with those numbers (`k+1` because it is not inclusive, but you need it to be), then we make it into a `list`.

---

Demo:

```
>>> k = int(input())
16
>>> numbers = list(range(k+1))
>>> numbers
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
```

Comment: This is for Python 3. In Python 2, this is simply `range(k+1)`.

Comment: @Alex Thornton thank you very much for your fast and complete answer.

Comment: Could the downvoter explain what is wrong with my post, so I might be able to improve it?

Answer (score 0):

A simple function would look like this, assuming you've got your input number `n`:

For python2.x:

```
def get_range(n):
    return range(n + 1)
```

For python3.x:

```
def get_range(n):
    return list(range(n + 1))
```

In either case:

```
int_list = get_range(10)

>>> print(int_list)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```